# sort linked list when the positive number first

Tags: c, linked-list

I try to sort linked list when the positive number first and the  negative number at the end , but i want to keep the original order

For exemple i insert :  3 , 1 , 4 , 6 , 7 , 8.

This is what i want :  4 , 6 , 8 , 3 , 1 , 7.

But this is what i get : 4 , 6 , 8 , 7 , 1 , 3

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



typedef struct node{
    int number;
    struct node *nextPtr;
} node;


node* insert(node* head, int num) {
    node *temp, *prev, *next;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->number = num;
    temp->nextPtr = NULL;
    if (!head){
        head = temp;
    }
    else{
        prev = NULL;
        next = head;
        while (next && next->number % 2 == 0){
            prev = next;
            next = next->nextPtr;
        }
        if (!next){
            prev->nextPtr = temp;
        }
        else{
            if (prev) {
                temp->nextPtr = prev->nextPtr;
                prev->nextPtr = temp;
            }
            else {
                temp->nextPtr = head;
                head = temp;
            }
        }

        return head;
    }
}

void free_list(node *head) {
    node *prev = head;
    node *cur = head;
    while (cur) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = prev->nextPtr;
        free(prev);
    }
}

int main(){

    node *head, *p;
    head = NULL;

    head = insert(head, 3);
    head = insert(head, 1);
    head = insert(head, 4);
    head = insert(head, 6);
    head = insert(head, 7);
    head = insert(head, 8);

    p = head;
    while (p) {
        printf("%d ", p->number);
        p = p->nextPtr;
    }
    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to have the list both sorted and in original order. Could you elaborate?

Comment: When writing positive/negative, do you mean even/odd ?

Comment: Agreed. Your "what I want" list doesn't look very sorted.

Comment: And "keep the original order" is kind of opposing the idea of sorting. So all in all your problem statement is extremely unclear.

Comment: should be flagged as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: I think the OP does mean even/odd. The example is clear enough.

Comment: Easiest way would be to make a new list by parsing the original list twice.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Any odd number is inserted right after the last even number in the list.
This effectively means that the sublist of odd numbers is ordered in reverse order of occurrence.

**Remedy**

Adjust `insert` as follows:

After

```
    while (next && next->number % 2 == 0){
        prev = next;
        next = next->nextPtr;
    }
```

add

```
    if ( num % 2 == 1 ) {
        while (next){
            prev = next;
            next = next->nextPtr;
        }
    }
```

**Improvement**

Even better wrt to efficiency and code maintainability would be to keep two `last` pointers for the sublists or 2 linked lists instead of one in the first place. As soon as both sublists have at least one entry you can always create one comprehensive list by simply linking the parts.

**Caveat**

This may not be what the OP wants. Her question is ambiguous and probably uses wrong terms.